# Creating a web service client from WSDL in java

Tags: java, wsdl

I have been searching for days on this, and finally figured I'd ask.  I'm new to java in general, and newer to web service functionality, so I'm struggling quite a bit.  I'm surprised I haven't found a step by step guide on this in all of the examples I've found on the net, but I'm sure there is something somewhere.  All I need to do is import a WSDL document into Java (done), and be able to invoke the web service from my class, send it a string, and have it return a response.  When I first import the WSDL into the project, there are several errors that exist.  The main one seems to be that it requires an interface named similar to the proxy class that was generated.  So I've done that, but other errors are in there as well.  Is it normal that you have to create code within the generated classes and do your own thing in there, or should the WSDL be more formatted and precise so that it's just plug and play?  I thought from a project I did years ago, that it was pretty much plug and play and you could just do import it and do String response = myService.call(String myString); and have it return a response just by referencing the classes generated by the WSDL.  Does anyone have any ideas where a beginner could learn how to invoke a web service based on a WSDL file?  I mean from square one, like what you need to import, where you need to get the .jar file references from (if needed), etc.  Just for reference, I am including the WSDL below.  Thanks for any insight!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://listeners.webtools.integrator.myserver.com" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://listeners.webtools.integrator.myserver.com">
<wsdl:documentation>MYListener</wsdl:documentation>
<wsdl:types>
  <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://listeners.webtools.integrator.myserver.com">
    <xs:element name="processMessage">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="inputMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return"
                         nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>

<wsdl:message name="processMessageRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:processMessage"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="processMessageResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="ns:processMessageResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="MYListenerPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="processMessage">
        <wsdl:input message="ns:processMessageRequest" 
         wsaw:Action="urn:processMessage"/>
        <wsdl:output message="ns:processMessageResponse" 
         wsaw:Action="urn:processMessageResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="MYListenerSoap11Binding" 
 type="ns:MYListenerPortType">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" 
     style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="processMessage">
        <soap:operation soapAction="urn:processMessage" 
         style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="MYListenerSoap12Binding" 
 type="ns:MYListenerPortType">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" 
     style="document"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="processMessage">
        <soap12:operation soapAction="urn:processMessage" 
         style="document"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>

<wsdl:binding name="MYListenerHttpBinding" type="ns:MYListenerPortType">
    <http:binding verb="POST"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="processMessage">
        <http:operation location="processMessage"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <mime:content type="application/xml" part="parameters"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="MYListener">
    <wsdl:port name="MYListenerHttpSoap11Endpoint" 
     binding="ns:MYListenerSoap11Binding">
        <soap:address location="http://10.221.55.206:20043/axis2/services/MYListener.MYListenerHttpSoap11Endpoint/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="MYListenerHttpSoap12Endpoint" binding="ns:MYListenerSoap12Binding">
        <soap12:address location="http://10.221.55.206:20043/axis2/services/MYListener.MYListenerHttpSoap12Endpoint/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="MYListenerHttpEndpoint" binding="ns:MYListenerHttpBinding">
        <http:address location="http://10.221.55.206:20043/axis2/services/MYListener.MYListenerHttpEndpoint/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wsimport` tool to generate all artifacts, and then organize them manually. Or simpler, install NetBeans and use its option „Generate Web service client from wsdl“. It will put all files at correct places and generate `jax-ws-catalog.xml` file. More info here:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html#creatingtheclient

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've actually created this several times, and looked at some other internal examples.  The problem is my background is AS400 RPG.  I've managed to create the classes from the WSDL, but it created a proxy class, which references the actual class from the WSDL.  I assume I have to create that class myself, but I figured it would have done it automatically.  I will follow the example from this document and see how it goes.  I might have already tried it, as I've tried about a million different things already.  :)

Comment: @user1420914 Don't have experience with AS400 RPG, but your WSDL looks regular, so I don't think that you should encounter any problems by using this approach. NetBeans is a really great tool to deal with SOAP-based Web services. If you face any problems, post here and we will try to help.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just had the developers of the web service give me an example of how to connect to it, I just basically used their code.  It basically used the imports from org.apache.commons and functions to send the stuff.

Comment: @user1420914 Excellent, glad that you resolved the issue. For the future I strongly recommend using NetBeans for this purpose.